# Function specialization doesn't work

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I'm having a problem with writing a function specialization.

```
template <class type>
void is(type tab, int n) {
    string key;
    int i, j;

    for(i=1; i<n; i++){
        key=tab[i];
        j=i-1;
        while(j>=0 && tab[j]>key){
            tab[j+1]=tab[j];
            j--;
        }
        tab[j+1]=key;
        }
    }

template <>
void is <char **> (char *tab[], int n){
    char* key;
    int i, j;

    for(i=1; i<n; i++){
        key=tab[i];
        j=i-1;
        while(j>=0 && strcmp(tab[j], key)>0){
            tab[j+1]=tab[j];
            j--;
        }
        tab[j+1]=key;
    }
}
```

If I'm correct, when I call the function with `is<char **>(tab, n)` the program should use the specialization. Even so, I can't even compile it. All I get is `sort.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of void is<char**>(char**, int)`. I'd be really grateful for any help given.

Comment: You don't need the `is<char**>` in either the definition or the call, just `template <> void is(char *tab[], ...)` is fine. But the code looks syntactically fine, are you defining it in a header that's being used in multiple `.cpp` files?

Comment: Also you don't specialize the function at all, you could just make an overload: `void is(char *tab[], int n) { .. }`. Overloads are simpler.

Comment: [No problem with the specialization.](https://ideone.com/Vtw6im).

Comment: Yes, it's in a header that's used in main. When I used `template <> void is(char *tab[], ...)` I got the same error. The point is that I need to use a template.

Comment: @gha.st That's wierd... Doesn't work in Dev-Cpp. I copied the code you wrote into a new file and it work. Still, my project doesn't.

Comment: @photons3432 If it's used in `main.cpp` *and* `sort.cpp`, then you'll need to make both functions `inline`.

Comment: I've included the header in both `main.cpp` and `sort.cpp`

Comment: void is <char **> (char *tab[], int n) try to replace [] => *.

Comment: @rAndom69 An array type of elements of type `X` in a function parameter list **is** a pointer type to `X`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem doesn't have all that much to do with template specialization beyond the fact that - since it is fully specialized - the second `is` isn't a template anymore.

And while templates may be defined in multiple translation units, normal functions may not be defined multiple times.

@Barry comes close to a solution, but forgets that the original template need not be `inline`, only the specialization.

This leads to the same two solutions as for any old function (remember: The specialization *is* any old function):

```
template <> void is <char **> (char *tab[], int n);
// definition in *one* .cpp file
```

and

```
template <>
inline void is <char **> (char *tab[], int n){
    /* ... */
}
```

However, [function template specialization is tricky and should often be avoided in favor of overloading](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm).